# html input text field with data enter of maxlength characters exceeds database column width due to multibyte characters

Tags: mysql, forms, character-encoding, mariadb

We allow multibyte input into user profiles on our website. We have run into an issue when the user enters the maximum allowed field width, but includes multibyte characters that cause the field to exceed the maximum width of the database column. Other than truncating the data, is there a general solution for this?

I was surprised after searching on this topic and not finding anything good about it, although there is a lot of discussion about character sets and related topics.

We are using MariaDB. The documentation seems to suggest that a uft8mb4 column should be able to hold the number of characters specified. However I have proven in our system that is not correct.

For example, in a varchar(60) field, we can store the 30-character string made up of 30 repetitions of ç. If one more character is added, an error is returned when writing to the database. The html form has maxlength of 60 and the db table has the column defined as follows:

`companyname` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

So possibly something is wrong with the way we are setting it up. Or perhaps the documentation and much online discussion is wrong; but I hardly think so.

What would be a general way to handle this situation? It seems defining all such columns to be double or quadruple the form field maximum (depending upon which character set is supported) is a messy way to accommodate the odd multibyte character. And counting the multibyte characters by scanning the bitwise representation of each field also seems to be a messy approach.

If nobody can point out the error of our ways to solve the dilemma, I would probably opt for the combination approach of (1) increasing the size of the character fields in the database by 10% or so while leaving the html maxlength as at present; (2) relying on the existing routine that truncates to the maximum database column width as we already do for defensive reasons.

EDIT:

I tried to put the code in as "code", but it would not format it properly.

1. Column definition:

   `companyname` varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
2. A value from table:

   select userid, companyname from user where userid = 855;

   | userid | companyname

   |    855 | Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§Ã§ |
3. Display of value on screen:

   Company Name

   çççççççççççççççççççççççççççççç
4. Attempt to add on character to the companyname:

   update user

   -> set companyname = concat(companyname, 'a')

   -> where userid = 855;

   ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'companyname' at row 1

The above shows that a varchar(60) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 column with 30 2-byte characters is "full". So what is wrong with my setup?

EDIT 2:

I looked into this a bit further. In fact I can write directly into the database via SQL a 60 character string of ç characters.

However, when I enter into the web form a string of ç characters, they are doubled in the database into a string of Ã§ characters. I can only enter 30 ç characters because the expansion causes them to take 60 characters. So the problem is the encoding difference.

I have in php.ini default_charset = 'UTF-8'. The definition of the column in question in the database is utf8mb4 as shown above in the original question.

So what is missing that is causing the expansion of the 30 character string in php UTF-8 into the 60-character string in the database?

EDIT 3:

I found the page at https://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql helpful. Most of the points are already in place. However one point is not--adding several lines covering character set in my.cnf, such as  default-character-set=UTF-8.

I will be working with the suggestions from that page.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you described neither with mariadb, nor with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

`VARCHAR(60)` allows 60 characters in *whatever* `CHARACTER SET` it is declared to hold.  For utf8mb4, that could take *up to* 240 *bytes*.

If you want to hold as much as someone might want to type, consider `TEXT`, which can hold 64K *bytes*, which is between 16K and 64K utf8mb4 *characters*.

The disk space consumed by `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` is only the number of bytes needed for the value, plus some overhead.

If you have lots of `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` columns, you *might* be hitting a limit on the *row* size.  But that does not seem to be the case.

Example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE c ( x VARCHAR(60) CHARSET utf8mb4 );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO c (x) VALUES ( REPEAT('ç', 60) );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO c (x) VALUES ( REPEAT('ç', 61) );
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'x' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LENGTH(x), CHAR_LENGTH(x), x FROM c;
+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(x) | CHAR_LENGTH(x) | x                                                                                                                        |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       120 |             60 | çççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççç                                                             |
|       120 |             60 | çççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççççç                                                             |
+-----------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer seems logical about "whatever character set", and also matches the documentation. However in my case I have a utf8mb4 column declared as varchar(60). I can add 30 multibyte characters into this field. If I add one more character, I get an error.

Comment: @JeffreySimon - Please show us your code.  My example put 60 2-byte characters in `VARCHAR(60)` without trouble.  You must be doing something different; let's focus on the diff.

Comment: I have revisited this question. At the present time I cannot duplicate the error condition from the original question. That is, while during the time I composed the question, I got solid errors. However, now it is just working. So I will have to look further into this.